# Jquery attr function not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Find the code below.  I would like to make work the same functionality in the IE.  I am struggling to make it work on IE 9.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var colors= ["#99b433", "#00a300", "#1e7145"];
        $(document).ready(function(){
            addBarColor();
        });

        var addBarColor = function(){
            $('#lineColors').html("");
            for(var color=0; color<colors.length; color++){
                //Loading List of colors
                var chartBarColor = colors[color];
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.style.width = "50px";
                li.style.backgroundColor = chartBarColor;

                //Adding Remove button to it.
                var remove = document.createElement('span');
                remove.id = "remove"+color;
                remove.style.cursor="pointer";
                remove.style.marginLeft = "40px";

                //remove.onclick = function(){removeBarColor(color)};

                //Adding x image
                var removeImg = document.createElement('img');
                removeImg.src = "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/diagona/icon/10/101.png";

                //Appedning everything to UL
                remove.appendChild(removeImg);
                li.appendChild(remove);
                $('#lineColors').append(li);

                $("#remove"+color).attr('onclick', 'removeBarColor(\''+color+'\')');
            }
        }

        //Removing the color from the array
        var removeBarColor = function (index){
            alert(index);
            colors.splice(index, 1);
            console.log(colors);
            addBarColor();
        };
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="lineColors">
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Jquery's attr() function doesn't seems to be working in IE 9.  Alternatively I tried this remove.onclick = function(){removeBarColor(color)};  this also doesn't seems to be working in IE9.

Hope my problem is clear.  Thanks for help in anticipation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you're talking about this `attr` line:

```
$("#remove"+color).attr('onclick', 'removeBarColor(\''+color+'\')');
```

Whether it works elsewhere or not, don't hook up event handlers like that if you're using jQuery (or even, frankly, if you're not); hook up handlers using modern techniques, esp. as it's really easy with the lib you're already using:

```
$("#remove"+color).on('click', removeBarColor.bind(null, color));
```

That relies on ES5's `Function#bind` (which can be shimmed); alternately, you can use jQuery's [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/#jQuery-proxy-function-context-additionalArguments):

```
$("#remove"+color).on('click', $.proxy(removeBarColor, null, color));
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/litan/1)

Either way, what that code does is create a new function that, when called, will call `removeBarColor` passing in `color` as the `index` argument (and setting `this` to nothing in particular; well, okay, in loose mode it'll be `window`, in strict mode it'll be `null`). Then it assigns that function as a `click` handler.

Another approach is to save the color on the element, and then have `removeBarColor` work by looking at the element that was clicked, but the above is the minimal-mods approach.